# Excel Macro that select cells with data and format as a table

Tags: excel, vba

I need to create a macro that selects all cells with data in them and formats as a table style medium 2. I have this code,

```
Sub A_SelectAllMakeTable()
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Dim rng As Range

    Set rng = Range(Range("A7"), Range("A7").SpecialCells(xlLastCell))
    Set tbl = ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, rng, , xlYes)
    tbl.TableStyle = "TableStyleMedium2"
End Sub
```

But for some reason it picks up cells that don't have data in them and formats then in the table. Do you know why that might be?

Comment: `xlLastCell` is unreliable. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-excel-with-vba) for how to find the true last row.

Comment: `Range("A7").CurrentRegion` if your table has no blank rows/columns and is surrounded by empty cells.

Comment: If you have data in your first column (usually), and assuming all your headers are populated, just get lastrow/lastcolumn values (various ways to do so), and use that to set your range.